# Using pushd command to change dirname "$0"

Tags: bash

Lets take an example of my dir structure

`jatin
 -- 1
   -- 1.1
 -- 2
 -- 3`

when I am in path jatin/1/1.1, I use a pushd command as ../../3. What happens after this pwd shows the path of directory 3 but dirname "$0" does not change. Is there any way pushd can change the dirname "$0".

Comment: Why should `$0` change at the same time as you change the current working directory?

Comment: The reason i wanted is that I want to execute a script present in dir 3.
The script is something like
```
readonly CUR_DIR=$(dirname "$0")
cp $CUR_DIR/example_file
```
But the dirname $0 is of path jatin/1/1.1 instead of jatin/3

Comment: `CUR_DUR=$PWD` ?

Comment: Is there any way other than this?

Comment: not sure what you are asking for. Please take some time to rephrase your question and make clear what you are about to do and what does not work. A small code example which demonstrates that would be perfect.

Answer (score 2):

`$0` will be set upon start of the script. It won't get changed by any action the script takes during runtime, including changing it's working directory.

Good news: The current working directory is available via the `${PWD}` environment variable:

```
cur_dir=${PWD}
```

Comment: Also, `$0` depends on how the script was run. If it was run as `jatin/1/1.1/script.sh`, then `$0` will be "jatin/1/1.1/script.sh"; if it was run as `/full/path/to/jatin/1/1.1/script.sh`, *that* is what `$0` will be; if someone `cd`ed to the directory it's in and runs it as `./script.sh`, then *that* is what `$0` will be; if it's in a directory in `$PATH`, and someone runs it as just `script.sh`, then that's all that'll be in `$0`. In short, `$0` tells you how the script was run, not where it is (and certainly not where you `cd`ed to later).

Comment: Yes. Thanks for making this clear. Furthermore, if the executing program has full control over the `exec..()` system call it can even pass `foo` as `$0` (or even `bar` ;) )